# What happened to the original bodies in Invasion of the Body Snatchers?

Tags: body-snatchers

We all know the concept of *Invasion of the Body Snatchers*: alien cells reproducing  Earthling cells, plants and animals. In the movie, when Jeff Goldbloom's character closed his eyes, the copy opened his, so can we assume that they feed off our brain waves? What happens to the human's bodies after the copies develop?

Comment: In the original book, the original bodies would dissolve as the pod-body replicated it. There was some technobabble about the transfer of atomic bonds.

Comment: Near the end of the film we see what happens to the body of one character (whom I would identify if I could conceal spoilers in a comment).

Answer (score 10):

In [the book by Jack Finney](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0684852586), the original bodies would decompose into their composite atoms as the pod duplicated the atomic bonds.

Chapter 16:

> “Yes, Doctor Bennell, your body contains a pattern, all living matter
> does—it is the very foundation of cellular life. Because it is
> composed of the tiny electrical force-lines that hold together the
> very atoms that constitute your being. And therefore it is a
> pattern—infinitely more perfect and detailed than any blueprint could
> be—of the precise atomic constitution of your body at exactly that
> moment, altering with every breath you take, and with every second of
> time in which your body infinitesimally changes. And it is during
> sleep, incidentally, when that change occurs least; and during sleep
> when the pattern can be taken from you, absorbed like static
> electricity, from one body to another.”
>
> Again he nodded. “So it
> can happen, Doctor Bennell, and rather easily; the intricate pattern
> of electrical forcelines that knit together every atom of your body to
> form and constitute every last cell of it—can be slowly transferred.
> And then, since every kind of atom in the universe is identical—the
> building blocks of the universe—you are precisely duplicated, atom for
> atom, molecule for molecule, cell for cell, down to the tiniest scar
> or hair on your wrist. And what happens to the original? The atoms
> that formerly composed you are—static now, nothing, a pile of grey
> fluff. It can happen, does happen, and you know that it has happened;
> and yet you will not accept it.” He watched me for a moment, then
> smiled. “Though perhaps I’m wrong about that; I think maybe you have
> accepted it.”

The [1956 movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0049366/?ref_=nv_sr_2) has the original bodies (or the duplicates, if the process was interrupted) just disappear. The [1978 movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0077745/?ref_=nv_sr_2) shows the newly-created pod people cleaning up piles of dust, and the original bodies breaking down as the duplication is completed, but it isn't really explained.

Answer (score 1):

The original film does NOT have the original bodies disappear when the process is successful. We know this from the cave where the doc and lady friend are on the run.
The doc leaves the human woman in the cave for a few minutes. When he returns and kisses her, he realizes she fell asleep as she is no longer human.

It's entirely unreasonable to assume that the developing pod somehow managed to track them down (when the entire alien population had no idea where they were) and switch places with the woman in those few minutes when the doc wasn't present. It would also assume the pod was animated and running around before the woman fell asleep. Aside from this feat requiring this particular pod to have some form of super GPS to track the human woman down, it would also have required a significant amount of time for the alien to run from town all the way to the hills and into the cave.

I have been baffled by this question for years. Would love to find a plausible explanation.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  If the original bodies don't disappear, where do they all go?  Can you provide a screenshot showing a the body of a duplicated human remaining?  The rest of this doesn't contribute to an answer; if you have a question about how it worked, you should ask it separately.  Check out the [tour] for more information on how the site works.

Comment: Clearly, whoever wrote the above "welcome" didn't read my response... or grasp it.   Thanks for the welcoming misplaced criticism.